# How to add, edit, update, delete element from array javascript and reactjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have below form:

[image]

And below is the table in which I am adding array elements:

[image]

I have a form from which I am adding values in an array using below code:

```
const {updateMode, lead_id, year, probability, plan2, plan3, fee, addcosts} = this.state;
this.setState(state => ({
                lead_plans: [...state.lead_plans, {
                    year: year,
                    probability: probability,
                    plan2: plan2,
                    plan3: plan3,
                    fee: fee,
                    addcosts: addcosts
                }]
            }));
```

Upon clicking edit button I am using below code:

```
let added_lead_plan = this.state.lead_plans.find(lead_plan_rec => lead_plan_rec.year === lead_plan.year);

            this.setState({
                plan_id: added_lead_plan.id,
                year: added_lead_plan.year,
                probability: added_lead_plan.probability,
                plan2: added_lead_plan.plan2,
                plan3: added_lead_plan.plan3,
                fee: added_lead_plan.fee,
                addcosts: added_lead_plan.addcosts,
                LeadPlanSaveUpdateDialogOpen: true,
            });
```

For deleting I am using below code:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({lead_plans: prevState.lead_plans.filter(lead_plan_rec => lead_plan_rec !== lead_plan_row)}));
```

Now,

Add Works fine.
Edit allows me to show the right values in edit form based on finding by date.

**Problems:**

I cant update the edited element in the array. Instead, it adds that records in the array again when it should update it.
But if someone, will edit the date how I can update the record based on date only - So, thats the other problem.

**Requirements:**

I need a way in which person can easily add as many values from form. Edit them one by one and update the only those in the array which got updated and delete the respective ones which were clicked delete.

**Edit**

```
{
                                (updated_lead_plans || existing_lead_plans || lead_plans).map((lead_plan, index) => (
                                    <TableRow key={`mi-${index}`}>
                                        <TableCell align="right" colSpan={2}>
                                            <TableCell align="right">
                                                <IconButton>
                                                    <EditIcon
                                                        onClick={() => this.handleUpdateFields(lead_plan)}/>
                                                </IconButton>
                                            </TableCell>
                                            <TableCell align="right">
                                                <IconButton>
                                                    <DeleteIcon
                                                        onClick={() => this.launchDeleteLeadPlanDialog(lead_plan)}/>
                                                </IconButton>
                                            </TableCell>
                                        </TableCell>
                                        <TableCell align="right">{moment(lead_plan.year).format("DD.MM.YYYY")}</TableCell>
                                        <TableCell align="right">{this.getFormattedNumber(lead_plan.probability)}</TableCell>
                                        <TableCell align="right">{this.getFormattedNumber(lead_plan.plan2)}</TableCell>
                                        <TableCell align="right">{this.getFormattedNumber(lead_plan.plan3)}</TableCell>
                                        <TableCell align="right">{this.getFormattedNumber(lead_plan.fee)}</TableCell>
                                        <TableCell
                                            align="right">{this.getFormattedNumber(lead_plan.addcosts)}</TableCell>
                                    </TableRow>
                                ))
                            }


handleUpdateFields = (lead_plan) => {

            let added_lead_plan = this.state.lead_plans.find(lead_plan_rec => lead_plan_rec.year === lead_plan.year);

            console.log('GGGG', added_lead_plan);

            this.setState({
                plan_id: added_lead_plan.id,
                year: added_lead_plan.year,
                probability: added_lead_plan.probability,
                plan2: added_lead_plan.plan2,
                plan3: added_lead_plan.plan3,
                fee: added_lead_plan.fee,
                addcosts: added_lead_plan.addcosts,
                LeadPlanSaveUpdateDialogOpen: true,
            });

    }

updateLeadPlanDialog = () => {
        const {updateMode, lead_id, plan_id, year, probability, plan2, plan3, fee, addcosts} = this.state;


            this.state.lead_plans.filter(lead_plan_rec => lead_plan_rec.year !== year);

            this.setState(state => ({
                lead_plans: [...state.lead_plans, {
                    year: year,
                    probability: probability,
                    plan2: plan2,
                    plan3: plan3,
                    fee: fee,
                    addcosts: addcosts
                }]
            }));


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
{
  (updated_lead_plans || existing_lead_plans || lead_plans).map(
    (lead_plan, index) => (
      <TableRow key={`mi-${index}`}>
        <TableCell align="right" colSpan={2}>
          <TableCell align="right">
            <IconButton>
              <EditIcon onClick={() => this.handleUpdateFields(lead_plan)} />
            </IconButton>
          </TableCell>
          <TableCell align="right">
            <IconButton>
              <DeleteIcon
                onClick={() => this.launchDeleteLeadPlanDialog(lead_plan)}
              />
            </IconButton>
          </TableCell>
        </TableCell>
        <TableCell align="right">
          {moment(lead_plan.year).format("DD.MM.YYYY")}
        </TableCell>
        <TableCell align="right">
          {this.getFormattedNumber(lead_plan.probability)}
        </TableCell>
        <TableCell align="right">
          {this.getFormattedNumber(lead_plan.plan2)}
        </TableCell>
        <TableCell align="right">
          {this.getFormattedNumber(lead_plan.plan3)}
        </TableCell>
        <TableCell align="right">
          {this.getFormattedNumber(lead_plan.fee)}
        </TableCell>
        <TableCell align="right">
          {this.getFormattedNumber(lead_plan.addcosts)}
        </TableCell>
      </TableRow>
    )
  );
};

handleUpdateFields = lead_plan => {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    lead_plans: prevState.lead_plans.map(item => {
      if(item.plan_id === lead_plan.plan_id){
        return {
          plan_id: added_lead_plan.id,
          year: added_lead_plan.year,
          probability: added_lead_plan.probability,
          plan2: added_lead_plan.plan2,
          plan3: added_lead_plan.plan3,
          fee: added_lead_plan.fee,
          addcosts: added_lead_plan.addcosts,
          LeadPlanSaveUpdateDialogOpen: true
        }
      }else{
        return item
      }
    })
  }));
};

updateLeadPlanDialog = () => {
  const {
    updateMode,
    lead_id,
    plan_id,
    year,
    probability,
    plan2,
    plan3,
    fee,
    addcosts
  } = this.state;

  this.state.lead_plans.filter(lead_plan_rec => lead_plan_rec.year !== year);

  this.setState(state => ({
    lead_plans: [
      ...state.lead_plans,
      {
        year: year,
        probability: probability,
        plan2: plan2,
        plan3: plan3,
        fee: fee,
        addcosts: addcosts
      }
    ]
  }));
};
```

I've changed your `handleUpdateFields` method.

but I don't know why you're doing this:

```
const {
    updateMode,
    lead_id,
    plan_id,
    year,
    probability,
    plan2,
    plan3,
    fee,
    addcosts
  } = this.state;
```

these values shouldn't be exist on your state because your state looks like this:

```
{
  lead_plans // which is an array of items 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in Order to edit correctly you need to do something like this:

use This Code for edit

```
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    lead_plans: prevState.lead_plans.map(item => {
      if(item.year === lead_plan.year){
        return {
          plan_id: added_lead_plan.id,
          year: added_lead_plan.year,
          probability: added_lead_plan.probability,
          plan2: added_lead_plan.plan2,
          plan3: added_lead_plan.plan3,
          fee: added_lead_plan.fee,
          addcosts: added_lead_plan.addcosts,
          LeadPlanSaveUpdateDialogOpen: true
        }
      }else{
        return item
      }
    })
  }));
```

and use this code for adding new item

```
 const {
    updateMode,
    lead_id,
    year,
    probability,
    plan2,
    plan3,
    fee,
    addcosts
  } = this.state;
  this.setState(state => ({
    lead_plans: [
      ...state.lead_plans,
      {
        year: year,
        probability: probability,
        plan2: plan2,
        plan3: plan3,
        fee: fee,
        addcosts: addcosts
      }
    ]
  }));
```

also keep in mind that `year` property is not a good indicator to compare, use `plan_id` instead;

Comment: But when user is inserting the value for the very first time (no db operation) he dont have any plan_id available in the form.

Comment: The other problem is that, you post snipt for editing in an array, I need to update that one in the array which was updated from form.

Comment: @LearningROR this is only for edit section for your update section use your update code, it was correct

Comment: @LearningROR As a general rule , when you click on an edit button you pass the selected Item id (or its data) to your edit function , then you will use this data in your edit form , finally when edit form has been submitted you check your old State and you will update with new result

Comment: but In adding new item you take the old items in ```state``` and will append the newly submitted form data as a new item to your state

Comment: Yes I am looking for that thing in which I can check my existing state and update the newly updated one the in array. Edit will load the right row data in form and clicking update will update only updated values in that array.

Comment: check my answer I've explained how to do add newly edited data to your state

Comment: Now I am not able to values in a modal. Its not opening my modal now with right edit row values in form...!

Comment: I don't know how you implemented it or how your code looks like , I've just showed you an example , if you want the exact answer you need to provide your code